# Remove caching for newly created node and updated page and block for quick access

Tags: 7, blocks, caching

I have caching enable. However I wanted my changes to show up without delay.
How can I remove caching for specific :

- page like the home page (too dynamic)
- blocks any time they are updated
- new created node which are not accessible immediately to anonymous because of caching.

`DRUPAL_NO_CACHE` was added to the specific block code to no avail ...

```
function mm_video_block_info() {   
  $blocks['mm_video_hero'] = array(    
  'info' => t('Hero Video'),    
  'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,    
  );     
return $blocks;
```

}